# Mobile Development Tools

Tags: mobile

I'm researching various tools available for developing and deploying an app to mobile devices.  The existing app is available in two versions: as a traditional desktop application and as a browser-based "Lite" version.  We're building out the features of the "Lite" version to make it a full implementation of the flagship software, but thinking about mobile development as well.

What are the best tools available for cross-platform deployment of an Internet-enabled application to mobile devices?  Which is the better way to go, native applications developed on a cross-platform API or a mobile-ready website?  What tools are available for each?

One person suggested looking into "Agile" as a solution.  I'm not quite sure what he meant, or even if that was the right reference ... does it ring a bell for anyone (I'm familiar with "agile development," but he was referring to "Agile" as a mobile development tool ...)?

Comment: By "mobile" what platform/devices do you plan to support? iPhone/iPad?, BlackBerry?, Android?, etc.  As for "Agile" that's more of a development philosophy/approach to development, not the software tool(s) to obtain cross-platform deployments.  That said, nothing against Agile, it does a good job of focusing your efforts on what matters to get your software out the door.

Comment: By "mobile" I mean any and all mobile devices.  That includes iPhone/iPad, Blackberry, Android, Palm, etc.  I've found some tools that claim cross-platform compatibility, but without actual experience in that arena I'm not sure.  Also, I know what agile development approaches are, but he was referring specifically to a tool (he suggested we buy Agile if it would help our workflow).  Is it possible he meant some other development tool?  Or might he just not understand the difference between dev tools and dev philosophies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out "Agile" was a misstep.  At the time, he was referring to tools like Mobify that automate the development and deployment of simple mobile websites.  For our situation (a membership-based RIA), though, this wouldn't work.

The best tools I *did* find, though, for anyone interested:

[Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)

- A fantastic JS library for building RIA system for the iPhone and Android
- GPL licensed for free software
- Commercial licenses are also available
- Uses HTML5 and CSS3 to deliver smooth animations and an incredibly "squishy" UI

[jQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/)

- Another great JS library (Sencha is actually based on this one).
- Built on jQuery, so it's an easy framework to learn
- MIT licensed - more versatile than GPL licensing when it comes to JS libraries
- Also uses HTML5 and CSS3

[Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/)

- A great library for interactive/animated SVG displays (I need to graph data, so this is important
- Also MIT licensed

In reality, Sencha Touch is based on both jQTouch and Raphael, so if you're looking for an all-in-one solution, I'd recommend you go that direction.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work well in situations where your server-side applications are closed-source (which is a necessary security requirement for medical or financial web applications).  Though Sencha does offer a corporate license, it's currently a "beta" license and they may or may not charge $199/developer in September (they're unsure of the schedule).  Their interpretation of the GPL is also more viral than most, so I would not recommend using their GPL license if there's any code on your site (even on the back-end) that would even remotely fall into non-compliance.